# jQuery DataTables on live tables from PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, html-table, live

I'm having a problem with the implementation of [DataTables](http://datatables.net), I simple can't make it work in a returned table from a PHP script. Suppose this simple PHP script named simple_table.php:

```
<?php
    echo '
    <table class="table_type">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
?>
```

Now I also have the next very simple jQuery script declared after the `</body>` tag in the hipotetic html file:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('table.table_type').dataTable();
} );

$('div.push_button li').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).closest('div').children('div.content');
    $.get('simple_table.php', {}, function(html_table) {
            content.html(html_table);
    } );
} );
```

What is needed to be made for this simple example to work and keeping in it simple? The problem is that there is no solution for this useful scenario of a dynamic table made by a so simple script!

Well, maybe you have to have a preexisting `<table>` and only yhen be able to filled up the respective `<tr>`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are running `.dataTable()` before the page has the element `table.table_type`. Instead of calling `.dataTable()` when the page loads, you need to run it once the table has been added to your `<div>`.

```
$('div.push_button li').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).closest('div').children('div.content');
    $.get('simple_table.php', {}, function(html_table) {
            content.html(html_table);
            content.find('table').dataTable();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, I realize that to after a while. Thanks.

    ...
        $.get('simple_table.php', {}, function(html_table) {
                content.html(html_table);
                $('table.table_type').dataTable( { bRetrieve: true } );
        } );
    ...